# What does the command "find ~/folder-name -type f | wc -l" do?

Tags: directory, delete

The context  https://askubuntu.com/questions/523672/it-takes-forever-to-delete-a-particular-folder-created-by-bleach-bit-while-freei
Also, could you take a look at the context that suggested by @VolkerSiegel in her/him comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523672/it-takes-forever-to-delete-a-particular-folder-created-by-bleach-bit-while-freei#comment712992_523672).

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm very interested in knowing how it ended up like that, and I think Alistair's suggestion is right.

Answer (score 3):

Let's split it into parts: 
`find ~/folder-name -type f | wc -l`

1. [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) is a program for, well, finding files and folders:

   - `~/folder-name` is the directory in which `find` will try to find files/folders
   - `-type f` tells `find` to look only for files (and not directories, special files, etc.)
2. [`wc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/wc.1.html) is a program to count characters, words, and lines in some text (a file, or the input that you give it).

   - `-l` tells it to only count lines.
3. `|` sends the output of `find` to `wc`.

All told, it counts the total number of files in the directory `~/folder-name`, and all its sub-directories. In your case you have 1305252 files, not counting links, directories and other special files. That's a pretty  big number (IIRC a MATLAB installation has around 500000 files, less than half that, and still takes forever to delete). That would go a long way in explaining the long times. The sheer amount of time `find` took should be hint.

As another reference point, my own home directory, with a total size of 361GB spanning a few partitions has only 282747 files (one fourth of your number!).

Answer (score -1):

It counts (`wc -l`) the number of regular files (`-type f`) that are found - recursively - in the directory `~/folder-name`.